# Store value after submit form - Array

Tags: php, arrays, submit

I have a form like this:

```
<input type="text" name="sth[]" />
<input type="text" name="sth[]" />
<input type="text" name="sth[]" />
<input type="text" name="sth[]" />
```

After submit I check some conditions and when there are errors I want to show form again but with posted values. How can I fill fileds like this?

Comment: `value="$_POST['sth']"`.

Comment: Can you show the code for validation

Comment: you validate with php or js? You should validate with js

Comment: Why he should do js validation @JonathandeM. Can you explain?

Comment: not reload the page, keep data in the input

Comment: So if js is  disabled it wont work.I recommend to use server side validations

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `value` attributes of your `<input>` tags, similar to this:

```
<input type="text" name="sth[0]" value="<?php echo $_POST['sth'][0]; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php code,

```
<?php
$total_inputs = 4;
if (isset($_POST['sth'])) {
$sth = $_POST['sth']);
} else {
$sth = array_fill(0, $total_inputs, '');
}
?>
```

In your html,

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $total_inputs, $i++): ?>
<input type="text" name="sth[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="<?php echo $sth[$i]?>" />
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $sth = array('','','','');
   if(isset($_POST[sth]) && count($_POST['sth']) == 4) {
      $sth = $_POST['sth'];
   }
?>

<input type="text" name="sth[]" value="<?php echo $sth[0]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="sth[]" value="<?php echo $sth[1]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="sth[]" value="<?php echo $sth[2]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="sth[]" value="<?php echo $sth[3]; ?>"/>
```

This code first fills the `$sth` variable with an array with four empty strings. Then it checks if the `$_POST['sth']` is not empty and the size equal to 4, if so, it overwrites the old array with the post data.
The `value="..."` will set the value of the current input field. So if `$_POST['sth']` is empty, the value of the input wil be `''`(empty string). But if `$_POST['sth']` is not empty the input value will be the value entered by the user.